# Function for snakes and ladders printing additional output that is not needed

Tags: c, function, project

I am trying to create a grid for my snakes and ladders project. I want to be able to create a grid wherein it will start from 99 to 90 then whenever the number at the end of the row is even I want the next row to start from the last number - 10 until last number - 1. For example, the second line of the grid will start from 80 to 89. I make a random generated number decide where the player and cpu will be positioned in the grid. If the player is in a certain number's position then an asterisk will replace that number. If the cpu is in a certain number's position then it will print a hashtag and replace that certain number. If both the player and the cpu are at the same position then an @ will be printed at that position. Every round the terminal clears and randomly generates new numbers then replaces the old position of the symbols with the number assigned in that position. At certain conditions for some reason two asterisks or two hashtags will appear in the grid which will cause the grid to shift forward twice, then an additional row will be created wherein a certain number will be printed 10 times, then the final row which is supposed to be starting from 0-9 is deleted.

My function's code

```
void print_board(int *player_move, int *opp_move)
{
    int i, j, k, num = 99;
    int temporary, even = 0;

    system("cls");

    /* prints top line */
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        printf("+----");
    }
    printf("+\n");


    for (i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < LIMIT; j++, num--) {
            if (num >= 0) {
                if (num == *player_move && num == *opp_move) {
                    printf("|  @ ");
                } else if (*player_move == num) {
                    printf("|  * ");
                } else if (*opp_move == num) {
                    printf("|  # ");
                } else if (even == 1 && num <= temporary) {
                    while (num <= temporary) {

                        if (num == *player_move && num == *opp_move) {
                            printf("|  @ ");
                            num++;
                            j++;
                        } else if (*player_move == num) {
                            printf("|  * ");
                            num++;
                            j++;
                        } else if (*opp_move == num) {
                            printf("|  # ");
                            num++;
                            j++;
                        } else{
                            printf("| %2d ", num++);
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                    j -= 1;
                } else if (even == 0) {
                    printf("| %2d ", num);
                }


                if (j == 9) {
                    if (num % 2 == 0 && even == 0) {
                        temporary = num - 1;
                        num -= 9;
                        even += 2;
                    }
                
                    if (even == 2 || even > 0) {
                        even -= 1;
                    }
                
                    if (even == 0) {
                        num -= 10;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (i <= LIMIT - 1) {
             printf("|\n");

            /* prints bottom line */
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                printf("+----");
            }
            printf("+\n");
        } else {
            // Last row, so only print a line of dashes
            printf("\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                printf("+----");
            }
            printf("+\n");
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

An example of the problem I am facing is happening is when the position of the player is at 20 and the position of the cpu is at 18. two additional asterisks will be printed between number 19, the grid will be pushed forward twice, then the row below it will be 29 which is printed 10 times. The final row which is supposed to be 0-9 is deleted. I want my final row to be the numbers 0-9, then get rid of the additional astrisk and row with the number 29 printed 10 times.

Here is how a part of the grid looks like.

```
 39 | 38 | 37 | 36 | 35 | 34 | 33 | 32 | 31 | 30 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  * | 19 |  * | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 29 | 29 | 29 | 29 | 29 | 29 | 29 | 29 | 29 | 29 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 19 |  # | 17 | 16 | 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 |
```

Comment: 1) Posted code does not compile cleanly.  Better to post a [mcve]  2) Post the desired output.

Comment: `if (i <= LIMIT - 1)` is always true.  Did you want something else?  Perhasp `if (i < LIMIT - 1)`?

Comment: Aside: `(i <= LIMIT - 1)` is harder to read than `(i < LIMIT)` and using that style in some cases can be error-prone.

Comment: Use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line to see what happens.

Comment: Consider holding the board state in a 2D(-ish) data structure that can be printed more directly, instead of effectively regenerating such a representation every time you print the board.

Comment: NB: Why are the moves given as pointers? That only makes sense if the values are supposed to be changed and the change to be visible outside the function, but the function doesn't do that. Which is a good thing because just printing the state of the board should not change the state anyway.

Comment: I would rewrite this instead of searching the error. It is way to convoluted. `num` and `j` are updated by the loop but also within the loop. At first I thought `even` is a flag that keeps track if the current row is even or odd and then there is a `even += 2;` and I don't know what that variable means anymore. `temporary` doesn't even attempt to give the reader a clue what this variable means. There are clearer ways to write this. The code to decide and print `*`, `#`, or `@` shouldn't be duplicated either. And maybe add some comments so we know what you think the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite this in a simpler way.  For instance by calculating the current field number from both loop counters in a formula instead of trying to update/adjust it in both loops.  Then we need just three local variables: the two loop counters and the field number calculated from them.  Also the decision which character to print or if the field number must be printed is just once in that code.

```c
void print_board(int player_position, int opponent_position)
{
    int i, j, field_number;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            field_number = 99 - i * 10 - ((i & 1) ? 9 - j : j);
            
            if (player_position == field_number && opponent_position == field_number) {
                printf("  @ ");
            } else if (player_position == field_number) {
                printf("  * ");
            } else if (opponent_position == field_number) {
                printf("  # ");
            } else {
                printf(" %2d ", field_number);
            }
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Output for the example values of 20 and 18 from the question:

```
 99  98  97  96  95  94  93  92  91  90 
 80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89 
 79  78  77  76  75  74  73  72  71  70 
 60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69 
 59  58  57  56  55  54  53  52  51  50 
 40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49 
 39  38  37  36  35  34  33  32  31  30 
  *  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29 
 19   #  17  16  15  14  13  12  11  10 
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```